# How to use Smartsheet- API to export specific data on Excel file

Tags: api, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am trying to find out if it's possible to use Smartsheet API or any other method to export specific columns data from Report Builder results to Excel file rather than the whole column that was generated from it. I am new to Smartheet and if you need better clarification or if there is any method to this approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results of a Report via the Smartsheet API. When you make the request the Report is run to give you the current results of the Report just as if you opened it in your browser. There is also a specific request in the Smartsheet API on Reports to get the data provided as an Excel file. With this you can then work with the data in Excel as you need. This request is listed in the Smartsheet API docs here:
http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-report-as-excel-csv

Comment: I have looked at the Get Reports section of the Smartsheet API and it shows that returns are limited to only 4 attributes which doesn't look like it can be used to returns specific columns but rather the data from that specific column. Is it possible to return specific columns with data included? for example, if you have 5 columns generated from the Report Builder and you want only 2 columns and data in those 2 columns to be exported into the Excel file.

Comment: It's not possible to specify only certain columns be given back in the results of the request. The entire report will be generated for the Excel file. You would need to write your own code that runs after the file is received to work with the data as you need.